# Verify an entity is translated

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I want to add a "add translation now" button on nodes and other entities too. I'm using the [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/Entity_Translation) module, and I added two languages to the site.

I thought about getting the original translation and then loop through the translation data, checking if there is more than just the original language inside.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you are doing field translation then there is no point of having translate now link at Node level. For this there is always translate primary tab for this. see in screenshot. [image]

Still if you want to achieve this functionality, loop through this array within node object.

```
$node->translations->data
```

Do this in module file in `hook_preprocess_HOOK` here it will be `hook_preprocess_node` and pass a variable to `node.tpl.php`

Comment: The translate tab is always there, even if the entity is already translated. I only want the button, if the entity is not translated yet.

Comment: count the number of all enabled languages. and match with count($node->translations->data) . if not matching show the button .